# Search bar result troubleshooting in php

Tags: php, html, ubuntu-16.04, lighttpd

I'm trying to build a code in php that will allow to me search (input filename given by the user) and display that file from my directory onto the website. Here is the code to display the downloadable pdf file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<title>Log Files</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Log Files</h1>

<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Date Modified</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php

// Adds pretty filesizes
function pretty_filesize($file) {
    $size=filesize($file);
    if($size<1024){$size=$size." Bytes";}
    elseif(($size<1048576)&&($size>1023)){$size=round($size/1024, 1)." KB";}
    elseif(($size<1073741824)&&($size>1048575)){$size=round($size/1048576, 1)." MB";}
    else{$size=round($size/1073741824, 1)." GB";}
    return $size;
}

// Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
{$hide="";
 $ahref="./";
 $atext="Hide";}
else
{$hide=".";
 $ahref="./?hidden";
 $atext="Show";}

$directory = "downloads/";  // or example: $directory = "uploads/";
// opens this directory
$myDirectory = opendir($directory);


// Gets each entry
while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
   $dirArray[]=$entryName;
}

// Closes directory
closedir($myDirectory);

// Counts elements in array
$indexCount=count($dirArray);

// Sorts files
sort($dirArray);

// Loops through the array of files
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

// Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
    if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1)!=$hide) {

// Resets Variables
    $favicon="";
    $class="file";


// Gets File Names
    $name=$dirArray[$index];
    $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

// Gets Date Modified
    $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
    $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));

// Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
    if(is_dir($dirArray[$index]))
    {
            $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;";
            $size="&lt;Directory&gt;";
            $sizekey="0";
            $class="dir";

        // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
            if(file_exists("$namehref/favicon-32x32.png"))
                {
                    $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon-32x32.png);'";
                    $extn="&lt;Website&gt;";
                }

        // Cleans up . and .. directories
            if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;"; $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon-32x32.png);'";}
            if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
    }

// File-only operations
    else{
        // Gets file extension
        $extn=pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Prettifies file type
        switch ($extn){
            case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
            case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
            case "jpeg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
            case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
            case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
            case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;

            case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
            case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
            case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "html": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "xhtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "shtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
            case "js": $extn="Javascript File"; break;
            case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;

            case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
            case "xls": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
            case "xlsx": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
            case "doc": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;
            case "docx": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;

            case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
            case "htaccess": $extn="Apache Config File"; break;
            case "exe": $extn="Windows Executable"; break;

            default: if($extn!=""){$extn=strtoupper($extn)." File";} else{$extn="Unknown";} break;
        }

        // Gets and cleans up file size
            $size=pretty_filesize($directory.$dirArray[$index]);
            $sizekey=filesize($directory.$dirArray[$index]);
    }
 $searchid = $_POST['search'];
 if($searchid == $namehref) {
         echo("<tr class='$class'>
        <td><a href='read.php?name_txt=$searchid'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='downloads/$searchid'>$extn</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='downloads/$searchid'>$size</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='downloads/$searchid'>$modtime</a></td>
    </tr>");
        }
    }


else {
    if ($searchid == null) {
 echo("
    <tr class='$class'>
        <td><a href='read.php?name_txt=$namehref'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='downloads/$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='downloads/$namehref'>$size</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='downloads/$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
    </tr>");
    }
  }
}
?>


    </tbody>
</table>

<h2><?php echo("<a href='$ahref'>$atext hidden files</a>"); ?></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to display the required search result. But the problem is that when the `search bar` is empty or `null` I want to display all the files from that directory which isn't happening. 
To be clear,

**The desired search result**

[image]

**The result I want to get when the search bar value is null**

[image]
**The result I get when the search bar is empty**

[image]
Can someone let me know where am I going wrong? Also I'm new to php.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if ($namehref == null)
```

with

```
if ($searchid == null)
```

If thats not fixing the issue, show us more code

Comment: I did the necessary changes, it still shows the same blank screen. I've updated the full code in the question. Please check it out and tell if I'm missing something

Comment: Try isset($_POST['search']) this should return false if the parameter post is set

Comment: I did  `isset($_POST['search'])`. It did make some change. I get the list of all files when the search bar is null.. but can't display a particular file even after passing it's name in the search bar.

Comment: for fixing such issues, the most easy way is to echo your `$namehref` and your `$searchid` and first look if they are equal, if there is a case mismatch or something similar just use one of those functions to compensate this: https://dzone.com/articles/how-compare-strings-php

Comment: the strings match.. I'm getting the search result.. all I want to do is when the search value is null, I want to display all the files that are there in the directory.